# Application logs not generated when JAR installed as an application

Tags: java, log4j, launch4j

I have a java application with log4j configured to log application logs. When i run it as java -jar the application logs are generated. But the i need to distribute the same application as windows installer so i used Launch4j and converted the JAR to an exe file. Then i used the exe file with Inno Setup to create a windows installer with JDK packaged in the installer. The application could be installed successfully under Program Files (x86)and running fine. But the application logs are not generated. When i created the JAR, during that packaging itself the log4j.xml is included in the JAR. So, it was part of the exe created by launch4j. The log4j.xml configuration is as below:

```
  `<appender name="DD_FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="File" value="logs/rolling_app.log" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}:%p %c{2} [%L] %x - %m%n" />
    </layout>
   </appender>`
```

I tried adding system variable as -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.xml in launch4j but no logs were generated.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: “./logs” need to exist.

Comment: Exited the application and created logs folder under Program Files x(86)/myapp and restarted the application. Still the log files are not getting generated.

Answer (score 0):

The relative path didn't work due to the reason as creating of file under the program files folder need administrator rights. This was further proved by the logs generating under the app folder when i start the application as Administrator. In log4j, i gave the full path as C:/logs/ and created logs folder under C drive. Now application log file is generated in normal start mode. As i can't expect the application to be started in administrator mode, i would be configuring a path outside of Program Files folder.